# How to start Docker without an internet connection?

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I am using Playfab for running my game servers, and in order to enable local debugging they've provided an image to run the game servers as container on Docker. However Docker doesn't even launch unless I am connected to the internet. Any Idea how to launch it without internet?

Comment: What command are you using, and what is the error you get?

Comment: @PierreB. Hey! Sorry for the unclear question. I can't even launch the application without internet connection. My company doesn't allow internet connections on our machine and blocks all incoming and outgoing traffic

Comment: Can you put the error output here? Maybe you were not able to download the Docker image. But without internet connection you'll be quite limited